# Compare two dictionaries (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, compare

I need to check if two dictionaries of type `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` are identical. So far I have this:

```
// dictionaries are already defined, so no parameters are required
private bool DictionariesEqual()
{
   return dictionary1.SequenceEqual(dictionary2);
}
```

I assume this only checks if the order of the keys and values is the same, which is not what I want because **the order doesn't matter, only the name of each key and value**.

Is there a way to check the dictionaries for unequal strings and return false if the first mismatch is found?

**EDIT**

Thanks for all your help but value changes are still not recognized.

To be more specific, here's the function (thanks @juharr) and how I use it:

```
private bool DictionaryContentChanged()
{
    if(synonymDictionary.Count != temporaryDictionary.Count ||
       synonymDictionary.Keys.Except(temporaryDictionary.Keys).Any() ||
       !synonymDictionary.Join(
            temporaryDictionary,
            kvp => kvp.Key,
            kvp => kvp.Key,
            (kvp1, kvp2) => new
            {
                l1 = kvp1.Value,
                l2 = kvp2.Value
            })
            .All(a => a.l1.Count == a.l2.Count && !a.l1.Except(a.l2).Any()))
            return true;
        return false;
{
```

I put it into an Update function that repeatedly checks for changes at a certain interval:

```
void Update(int interval)
{
    while(!this.IsDisposed)
    {
        Set.Timer(interval);

        if(DictionaryContentChanged())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Changes detected");
        }
        else
        {
            // move on
        }
    }
}
```

When I add, remove or change a value nothing happens. The message box only shows up if a key is altered or the key.Count is changed. Might this be related to the function that compares the dictionaries?

Please remember that the value of of each KeyValuePair represents a generic List.

Comment: May I ask why you un-excepted my answer?

Comment: Sorry. It's because I hastely accepted it, when I realized that dictionary key changes were registered, but when I realized that value changes are not seen by your comparison, I un-accepted your answer.

Comment: Are your values within the list actually strings or any arbitrary objects? In first case my solution should work, othwerwise you should implement Equals (and GetHashCode) on every possible type of object.

Comment: Both dictionaries contain plain strings and string lists of course. The relevant class is quite large, around 900 lines of code. I guess I'll have to dig through it some more to see what causes this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested but I guess the following may work:

```
if (dictionary1.Count != dictionary2.Count) return false;
foreach (var kv in dictionary1) {
    if (!dictionary2.ContainsKey(kv.Key) return false;

    List list = dictionary2[kv.Key];
    if (!list.Count != dictionary1[kv.Key].Count) return false;

    foreach(var value in kv.Value) {
        if(!list.Contains(value)) return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

EDIT: I added some length checks.

Comment: Accepted because it also recognizes changes of strings, all other approaches didn't. Thank you!

Comment: +1 You should probably add some length checks as a longer dictionary2/dictionary2 list could pass these tests

Comment: @Alex K. May I ask how I would do that? Should I compare the sum of entries of both dictionaries?

Comment: Count should be before the loop, it wont change!

Comment: @Richard The line before that checks for the key and if it isn't there it returns false.

Comment: @juharr Sorry, I read to fast ! Apologies. I delete my comment since it's became pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Linq version

```
dic1.Count == dic2.Count &&
!dic1.Keys.Except(dic2.Keys).Any() &&
dic1.Join(
    dic2,
    kvp => kvp.Key,
    kvp => kvp.Key,
    (kvp1, kvp2) => new
    {
        l1 = kvp1.Value,
        l2 = kvp2.Value
    })
    .All(a => a.l1.Count == a.l2.Count && !a.l1.Except(a.l2).Any())
```

First it makes sure the dictionaries have the same number of items, then it makes sure they have the same keys.  Then it joins them on their keys, and makes sure that all the lists with the same keys have the same count and the same contents.

**Edit**

Here's some ways to get the opposite return value.

Wrap the entire thing with () and put a ! in front.

```
!(dic1.Count == dic2.Count &&
!dic1.Keys.Except(dic2.Keys).Any() &&
dic1.Join(
    dic2,
    kvp => kvp.Key,
    kvp => kvp.Key,
    (kvp1, kvp2) => new
    {
        l1 = kvp1.Value,
        l2 = kvp2.Value
    })
    .All(a => a.l1.Count == a.l2.Count && !a.l1.Except(a.l2).Any()))
```

If you distribute the not then you get this, notice that you have to change the ands (`&&`) to ors (`||`).

```
dic1.Count != dic2.Count ||
dic1.Keys.Except(dic2.Keys).Any() ||
!dic1.Join(
    dic2,
    kvp => kvp.Key,
    kvp => kvp.Key,
    (kvp1, kvp2) => new
    {
        l1 = kvp1.Value,
        l2 = kvp2.Value
    })
    .All(a => a.l1.Count == a.l2.Count && !a.l1.Except(a.l2).Any())
```

This is based on [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) that states that

```
Not(A And B) = Not A Or Not B
```

Another option is to change your method from `DictionaryContentChanged` to `DictionaryContentSame` and just negate it where you use it if needed.

Comment: Awesome Linq snippet! But your and HimBromBeeres approach won't recognize any changes in the value List<> of a key (names, count). Can this be changed by a small addition to your snippet?

Comment: @betaFlux I don't understand what you mean.  This will make sure the lists with the same key have the same values regardless of order.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Please have a look at my question again. I added some information.

Comment: @betaFlux you're missing a not `!` in front of the part that compares the keys `!synonymDictionary.Keys.Except(temporaryDictionary.Keys).Any()`.

Comment: I actually changed all equality checks to the opposite to gain an opposite end result. As for the values, still no luck.

Comment: @betaFlux See my edits on how to negate the logical expression.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed insight. Just to make sure, something else is wrong: Your Linq method is able to catch differences in strings (value names) without a doubt?

Comment: I find it really complex for a rather simple check, and it the last part must perform poorly due to join/except/new type. HimBromBeere proposal looks to be faster and is more readable/straighforward.

Answer (score -1):

Sort both dictionaries and compare it

```
bool result2 = dictionary1.OrderBy(r=>r.Key).SequenceEqual(dictionary2.OrderBy(r=>r.Key));
```

Comment: This will not work because it compares the lists by reference and not by their contents.